# I want to classify locations (defined by longitude and latitude) according to the Loc..quality column

Tags: r, ggplot2, classification

```
" Longitude Latitude Loc..quality
1  22.33496 44.70298            1
2  22.33924 44.69002            0
3  22.34901 44.68629            A
4  22.58998 44.83182            B
5  22.38683 44.66142            B
6  22.35649 44.70147            A
"
```

I would like to plot (using ggplot2) the points after classifying them to Loc.. quality, so that the plot will show the points with different shapes and colors according to Loc..quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do by specifying color using factor levels

```
#Say you have a dataframe data storing these columns
data$Loc..quality = as.factor(data$Loc..quality)
ggplot(data,aes(Latitude,Longitude,color=Loc.quality)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: It really helped me, thanks a lot buddy !! :D